# Is there a proper way to prove that $f:[a,b] \to[a,b]$

Tags: numerical-methods

Is there any proper way to know whether a function has the same domain and range $[a,b]$ where $a,b<\infty$ i.e. $f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ ?

For example: 
$$
f(x) = e^{−x} ,\qquad [\ln(1.1), \ln(3)]
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate? The question is a bit unclear to me the way it is now.

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: @malit.tilak Is that what you meant? If not, then go to edit and click rollback.

Comment: yes @SwapnilTripathi It is what I meant.

Comment: Does the function have to be bijective? Or is it okay as long as $f(x)\in [a, b]$ for all $x\in [a, b]$?

Comment: It's OK as long as .....

Answer (score 1):

The solution very much depends on the function itself, but you can make some general points

Start by finding the minimum and maximum of $f$ in the interval, if the minimum is $a$ and the maximum is $b$ then (assuming $f$ is continuous) the range is the same. If $f$ is not continuous then the range might be $[a,b]$ and it might be a subset of $[a,b]$. If the minimum is larger than $a$ and/or the maximum is smaller than $b$, then the range will always be a proper subset of $[a,b]$.

If and only if the maximum of $f$ is larger than $b$ and/or the minimum is smaller than $a$ then the range will contain elements outside of $[a,b]$.

It's worth noting that if the range is a subset of $[a,b]$, then depending on your definition of range, it might be okay to expand the range to be exactly $[a,b]$, note that the function wouldn't be surjective if you do this.

---

As for your example
$$f(x)=e^{-x},\qquad[\ln(1.1),\ln(3)]$$
Let's find the minimum: the function $f$ is decreasing so the minimum is $e^{-\ln(3)}=\frac13$

Since $\dfrac13<1=\ln(1)<\ln(1.1)$ the function does not have the same range and domain.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just trying to find if the range $\subseteq$ the domain, it suffices to check that $\max f \le b$ and $\min f \ge a$. If the function is twice differentiable, the maximums are located at those $x$ where $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)<0$, or at the endpoints $a, b$. The minimums are located at those $x$ where $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)>0$, or at the endpoints $a, b$.